# Saving login info and other safe info connected to user login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, session-cookies

currently im using the "standard" login when you authenticate a user with a sqlcheck and a cookie to store the information. (As shown in the code example). Now i want to store some more information about the customer here. For example if he´s logged in as admin or not, what department he chooses to authenticate against etc. What would be the best approach for this? (Session, cache, store the info on propertys on the user)

Been looking around but haven´t found the best answer concerning security and standard for the MVC3 framwork. Since im kind of new to the MVC i want to "dig in" to the right habbits straight away... anny suggestions/opinions appreciated.

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(LoginModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (model.Username == "qwe" && model.Password == "qwe")// Proper 
                                   sql authentication to be implemented here
            {   
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(model.Username, false); 
                // True or false determents if its a persistent coockie or not



            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            } 
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Wrong login information");
            }
        }
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the aspnet sql membership provider?  If so, you could use the [Authorize] attribute with roles.  That way you could lock down the site base on a site role, such as admin.  You can extend the membership provider to have custom properties per user.  It is hard to tell if this would be sufficient.  I think we would need to know what are all the user properties you want to add and what functionality they provide.  For example, if they are in a department what can they do or not do.

Comment: Im using the AspNetSqlMembershipProvider but kindof "outOfTheBox" so havent really found to much info/tutorials about how to use it fully. I followed a tutorial on www.asp.net (the pluralsite guy) and what it covered was to create a LoginModel model, use it to get the data and then we basically just turned on the stuff in the config file. And set some basic access levels. 

What im trying to implement is a storage system for shops and they need to login to their own stores (eg. just seeing their own products etc.) so i need this info to be easily accessed globally.

Comment: @PerSvensson - No, you should NOT make it "easily accessed globally", for a lot of reasons.  That's desktop application thinking, not web application thinking.  Web apps and desktop apps are different things, and they have different ways of doing things.  By trying to make things "globally accessible" you will cause yourself a lot of pain over the long run.

Answer (score 0):

For authenticaiton, you should be using something IPrincipal based, such as FormsAuthentication or WindowsAuthentication.  You would use the `[Authorize]` attribute to prevent access, and to control which roles have access to the method (ie `[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]`).

For more fine grained authenticaiton, you check the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` or `User.IsInRole()` method (ie.

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrator")) {
    <your code for only an administrator>
}
```

You can use the same technique to lookup a role for department if you want, or lookup their department based on their user id using `User.Identity.Name`.